# Why is a certain boolean false though it should be true?

Tags: java

I wrote a Java program that should support English and German language. If a parameter is set and if it equals "english" or "English", it shall call a method that does the English version and if there is no parameter or it doesn't equal "English" or "english", it shall call the method for the German version.
However, (args[0]=="english"||args[0]=="English") is false no matter what my parameter is, even if it should be true and I don't get why that's the case.

Here is the main method, the other ones aren't important, so I'll leave them away.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
boolean input=args.length==1;
System.out.println(input);
boolean mode = false;
if (input) mode=args[0]=="English"||args[0]=="english";
System.out.println(mode);
if(input&&mode) english();
else german();
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why it won't be true, regardless of my parameter?

Comment: The println calls are unnecessary, I just put them there to find out why the english method is never called.

Comment: This is most likely explained in any Java FAQ.  Don't compare strings with ==

Comment: This question has an extra dimension not covered by [How do I compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832): locales. For natural language comparison the collation API should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `equals()` method for String value comparison.

```
args[0].equals("English")||args[0].equals("english")
```

or even better(in this case)

```
args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("English")
```

`==` is for object reference comparisons. Don't use it for comparing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Strings should not be compared with == but with equals method.
Use

```
args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("English")
```

it will compare for both, "english" and "English".

better version is

```
"English".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0]);
```

this will make sure, if args[0] is null, i.e no argument in your case, it will not throw NPE.

**Explaination** : Because in Java, == compares objects not there values, i.e if two references are holding same object or not. Objects content are compared with equals method of Object class, which String class overrides.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings in Java in this way because Java Machine compare pointers to the string objects. To make correct compassion use function `equals`:

```
if( "english".equalsIgnoreCase( args[0] ) ) {
    // English language
}
```